# How can I track a Bug fix for safari?

Tags: macos, safari, local-storage, bug-tracker

We have been seeing issue on safari, starting safari 14.1 (MAC OS 11.3), where, Local-storage was not synchronised across tabs (more info:https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1389493762129375232 ),  It was not fixed in the recent MAC OS release - 11.4 as well.
How can we track such bugs? How can we know, which future release is tracking this update?

**Background:**
Copied from tweet: Tabs end up with separate localStorage for reading, but the same localStorage for writing. This will likely result in data loss for users. [More info here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225344). Also, any cross-tab communication that relies on the 'storage' event.

Comment: Shouldn't that be asked in "Super User"?

Comment: @U.Windl I have posted the question there as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see similar questions asked in different forums, no replies there either https://www.reddit.com/r/Safari/comments/n4laaq/localstorage_is_broken_in_safari_141/ Is there an easier way to keep track of safari related bugs?

Comment: Maybe see https://benfrain.com/reporting-browser-bugs-chrome-firefox-safari-teams-gets-fixed/ or specifically https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: @U.Windl https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225344 , says it is resolved. However, I was more interested in understanding, when this fix actually makes it to release. Track that fix in that sense.

Comment: Well, Apple is basically a proprietary system, defending intellectual property.